# pause and resume Selenium execution

Tags: java, python, selenium

I am looking for an option to pause and resume Selenium execution.

1. start the selenium execution

**2. pause at a certain step explicitly by some means (commandline/in-line code/manually)**

3. continue execution

I know that we can keep

```
Thread.sleep()
```

or

```
time.sleep
```

I want to give the pause dynamically in between the execution of a test case.

Programming language can be Java or Python.

is there a way in java or python to pass a pause to the execution dynamically?(probably that can help)

Any thoughts and solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way where we can do dynamically(no explicitly mentioning breakpoints or typing a line of code at a particular step).Get the process ID of my selenium script and fire below two commands for pausing and continuing whenever I want.

```
kill -SIGSTOP [pid]

kill -SIGCONT [pid]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an IDE, set breakpoints, and debug your script.

Answer (score 0):

For Python, use can use `pdb` for debugging. Just drop the following line at the step where you want to pause and it will drop you into the debugger.
You might have to get a little familiar with [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```